# Combining three.js and KineticJS - 3D cube

Tags: 3d, three.js, kineticjs

I am trying to add a 3D cube to Kinetic JS canvas to show the x,y,z rotation.  I found this article http://www.tonicodes.net/blog/combining-three-js-and-kineticjs. I worked with version 3.8, When I tried to follow the example using the version 4 of Kinetic JS I got this error,

```
 Unable to get property 'appendChild'
```

Any suggestions, to solve it or a better method to include 3D cube in the canvas.

complete project http://jsfiddle.net/user373721/hXw6D/1/

I found this perfect example http://html5example.net/entry/html5-canvas/html5-canvas-pre3d-rotating-cube, unfortunately it is based on pre3d.js and I have no clue how to integrate with Kinetic JS canvas.

Comment: Maybe I should answer it myself :) I'll look into it ;)

Comment: That will be great if you have time, go project.

Comment: A jsfiddle is always nice ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I have managed to fix my sample from the linked blog post, see the result here: http://tonicodes.net/sandbox/html5/kthree/index.htm.

Several things have changed from my last post.:

**Kinetic initialization is done differently now:**

```
stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: "container",
    width: 700,
    height: 700
});
```

**Also, you should supply `canvas` element provided by HTML5, not the one Kinetic wraps around it:**

```
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({canvas: layer3D.getCanvas().getElement()});
```

I also fixed your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hXw6D/3/, check it out. You forgot to add another `div` element with id *container*.

Comment: Thank you so much Toni, your solution by integrating simple 3D objects into 2D canvas is a great alternative to WebGL becasue of the current browsers limited support.  It will be great if the animation is controled by the mouse similar to this example  http://html5example.net/entry/html5-canvas/html5-canvas-pre3d-rotating-cube, also will it be possible to change the 6 panels of the cube to images.  Thanks again.

Comment: is the 3d cube being rendered in a 3d context or 2d?

Comment: In this case, in a 2d context. This is because I am using CanvasRenderer.