# How to add 3D perspective to image in a shape using kinetic js

Tags: kineticjs

How to add 3D perspective to image in a shape using kinetic js ? And how to add new custom shape onclick of a button to the layer with different reference name and refer any of the shape that i click using kinetic js ?

Comment: I just tried inserting image into shape and am new to kinetic js ..so i want to know is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to combine Kinetic JS *and* Three JS. Three JS is a 3D library that just gets the job done easily when you need to deal with three-dimensional shapes. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698371/combining-three-js-and-kineticjs-3d-cube#answer-15730023).

Here's part of a [working example](http://tonicodes.net/sandbox/html5/kthree/index.htm) from his blog ([Combining three.js and KineticJS](http://www.tonicodes.net/blog/combining-three-js-and-kineticjs/)):

```
stage = new Kinetic.Stage("container", 700, 700);
layer3D = new Kinetic.Layer();

renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({canvas: layer3D.getCanvas()});
renderer.render(scene, camera);

layerGUI.draw();
```

In my opinion, the main challenge in using Three JS is that rather than in 2D you have to position the camera in space.