# how to add css style to kineticjs

Tags: css, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I want to use this piece of css style to my kineticjs code to a particular rectangle to give 3D effect.

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-webkit-transform: perspective(375px) rotateY(65deg) translate(68px, -38px) rotate3d(0.65, 1, 1, -144deg) translate3d(2px, 81px, -38px);
```

Thank you all

Comment: You can't style canvas content with CSS - what's drawn on the canvas is subsumed into a collective image, they're not DOM elements.

Answer (score 2):

Like Utkanos said, you cannot apply CSS to content within a canvas.

KineticJS doesn't support 3D but it looks like you can integrate with Three.JS to get some 3D results. Check the following links...

[Combining three.js and KineticJS - 3D cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698371/combining-three-js-and-kineticjs-3d-cube)

http://www.tonicodes.net/blog/combining-three-js-and-kineticjs/

Comment: +1. Yep, there's no CSS styling available in KineticJS and threeJS is one answer for 3D drawing.  You might expand your answer to let the questioner know not to expect the same user-interactivity in ThreeJS that is available in KineticJS.  (KineticJS shines in user-interactivity while threeJS is programmatically driven.)